# How to change boost path

Tags: firebreath

I would like to recreate my build/ folder with prep2010.cmd and also set the boost folder to my own boost installation.

I run:

```
prep2010.cmd -D WITH_SYSTEM_BOOST=1 -D BOOST_ROOT="c:\boost"
```

But when I open the plugin solution the boost include folder is still set to firebreath's one. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=off so findboost.cmake will be able to match my boost binaries. My boost libs use shared runtime libs.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
prep2010.cmd "-DWITH_SYSTEM_BOOST=1" "-DBOOST_ROOT=C:\boost"
```

The windows prep scripts are a little funny; we haven't been able to figure out why they act that way, but if someone with more batch file experience than I have wants to fix them they are welcome to do so =]

Comment: Thanks, that brings me one step further. But, I still have some errors that the script cannot find some libs. The full error output you can find here. http://pastebin.com/dQ7Bj3vV  .