# How to change boost path for pip3 install?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install a python package using pip3. The python package at some point during installation runs cmake which requires boost (libboost-dev) of version 1.58.

The issue I have is that I have two boost installed, one in /usr/local/include and one in /usr/include. The one in /usr/include is version 1.58, as seen by typing

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

However, the cmake command finds the version in /usr/local/include, which is 1.54 and too old.

One recommended solution (see [How to change boost path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678758/how-to-change-boost-path)) seems to be to set the environmental variable BOOST_ROOT, but running export BOOST_ROOT="/usr/include" before pip does not make a difference.

The other recommended solution is to pass a flag to cmake that sets the path. However, since cmake is run somewhere inside pip3 install, I have no idea how to do that. How to solve this issue, by eg either getting rid of my old boost version or by forcing cmake/pip3 to use my new version (or updating the boost version in /usr/local/include)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export BOOST_ROOT=/usr
export BOOST_INCLUDE=/usr/include
export BOOST_LIBDIR=/usr/lib
```

PS. Why don't you remove outdated boost from `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: funny, that is exactly what I tried but my cmake file could still not find the variable, but now when I do it again it actually works. However, I already solved it by modifying the FindBoost.cmake file and adding a set(ENV{BOOST_ROOT} "/usr/include") instead. Did not dare to just delete the old boost lib by hand without a proper uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove (although I recommend renaming it until you are sure) the older boost entry in the global `CMake` package registry. On `Linux` it should be here:

```
 ~/.cmake/packages/<package>
```

Comment: I have no folder called .cmake, could it be located somewhere else?

Comment: Unless you have never run `CMake`, it should exist. What happens when you type `cd ~/.cmake` in the command line?